# Port forwarding in apache with additional parameter

Tags: apache, proxypass

How can I forward all incoming requests on one port say 8000 to another port say 8081, & add a static parameter in all request url while forwarding so that I can check for that specific parameter in my script?

Comment: Please provide your attempts at it.

Comment: Currently I am doing this by redirecting the all the incoming requests to a single php script then redirecting those requests to new port after adding a parameter in urls.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rules in your root htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8000$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8081%{REQUEST_URI}?param=value [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this solution didn't work for me.